# How add a column with a value based on the value of a field in a row?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

let's say I have this kind of dataframe:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~ID,~Reply_to_ID, ~author,
  14,  NA,      "John",
  16,  14,      "Jack",
  18,  14,      "John",
  20,  22,      "Annie",
  22,  24,      "Peter",
  24,  16,      "Annie"
)
```

Every ID is unique for a message
Every message can be a reply to another message

What I'd like is an extra column with the name of the author of the message replied to.
For example, Jack replies to message `14`, which was written by `"John"`, then John also replies to his message, so I'd have something like

```
  ~ID,~Reply_to_ID, ~author, ~Replied_to_author,
  14,  NA,      "John", NA,
  16,  14,      "Jack", "John",
  18,  14,      "John", "John",
  20,  22,      "Annie", "Peter",
  22,  24,      "Peter", "Annie",
  24,  16,      "Annie", "Jack"
)
```

Possibly, I'd like to use tidyverse to deal with the problem.

What I've tried so far has been something like

```
newDF <- mutate(
  df,
  Reply_to_author = filter(df, .data$id == .data$reply_to_message_id)
)
```

And stuff among the line. I know I can get the value by using something like `filter(df, id == 14)$author` , but I can't seem to be able to use `mutate` to create a new column for that value.

I hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can ``` match``Reply_to_ID ``` to `ID` to get corresponding `author`.

In base R, we can do this using `transform`

```
transform(df, Replied_to_author = author[match(Reply_to_ID, ID)])
```

To fit this into `tidyverse` we can use `mutate` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Replied_to_author = author[match(Reply_to_ID, ID)])

#     ID Reply_to_ID author Replied_to_author
#  <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  <chr>            
#1    14          NA John   NA               
#2    16          14 Jack   John             
#3    18          14 John   John             
#4    20          22 Annie  Peter            
#5    22          24 Peter  Annie            
#6    24          16 Annie  Jack
```

Comment: Damn, I spent good part of yesterday evening and this morning... and yet it was so easy.
Thanks!

Comment: ty, much cleaner than using `case_when()`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Replied_to_author := author[match(Reply_to_ID, ID)]][]
```